# When moving the Docker in Ansible, it does not allow you to specify the dns

Tags: docker, ansible

I'm not good at English,Sory.

I am a Ansible, are making a Docker.
But it can not successfully set the DNS.

Error Message:

```
TASK [data container] **********************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "msg": "Docker API Error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string"}
```

My main.yml

```
- name: data container
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    base_image: ubuntu_python
    docker_hostname: hoge
  tasks:
    - name: data container
      docker: name={{docker_hostname}} image={{ base_image }} state=started dns=["8.8.8.8"]
```

I tried the following things, but did not succeed.

```
dns=8.8.8.8
dns="8.8.8.8"
dns=["8.8.8.8"]
```

thank you for reading.
Please help me

ansible-playbook main.yml -vvvv

```
    fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "invocation": {"module_args": {"cap_add": null, "cap_drop": null, "command": null, "count": 1, "cpu_set": null, "debug": false, "detach": true, "dns": "8.8.8.8",
 "docker_api_version": "1.22", "docker_url": null, "docker_user": null, "domainname": null, "email": null, "env": null, "expose": null, "extra_hosts": null, "hostname": null, "image": "ubuntu_python", "insecure_registry": false, "links": null, "log_driver": null, "log_opt": null, "lxc_conf": null, 
"memory_limit": 0, "memory_swap": 0, "name": "hoge", "net": null, "password": null, "pid": null, "ports": null, "privileged": false, "publish_all_ports": false, "pull": "missing", "read_only": null, "registry": null, "restart_policy": null, "restart_policy_retry": 0, "signal": null, "state": 
"restarted", "stdin_open": false, "stop_timeout": 10, "tls_ca_cert": null, "tls_client_cert": null, "tls_client_key": null, "tls_hostname": null, "tty": false, "use_tls": null, "username": null, "volumes": null, "volumes_from": null}, "module_name": "docker"}, "msg": "Docker API Error: json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type []string"}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
name: data container
  docker:
    name: {{docker_hostname}}
    image: {{base_image}}
    state: restarted
    dns: ["8.8.8.8"]
```

Comment: I'm sorry reply late.
I tried as was said . But was the same error.
Thank you for your reply

Comment: I have appended -vvvv Result. So I want you to look again

Comment: And your answer becomes a hint , it was solved.Thank you.    - name: data container
      docker:
        name: "{{docker_hostname}}"
        image: "{{base_image}}"
        state: started
        dns: ["8.8.8.8"]

Answer (score 0):

- name: Creating PostgresSql container
  docker_container:
  name: postgresql
  image: postgresql:latest
  **dns_servers:**

  - 172.10.0.1
    volumes:
  - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
  - /data/postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    ports:
  - "5432:5432"
    networks:
  - name: ultimategames
    env:
    TZ : "Asia/Kolkata"

  tags: [always, thirdparty]

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Your answer could be better, since it's not very well structured, and it's very difficult to understand what you are answering. Please make an attempt at improving your answer, or consider if it belongs here. You can help others by improving your answers by reading this resource: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer